# Is the author's cast-based implementation of an optional<bool> well-defined in P2641?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing, type-punning, c++26

In [P2641r4: Checking if a union alternative is active](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2641r4.html), the author provides an implementation of an `optional<bool>` as a motivating example and claims that this is well-formed.

> ```cpp
> struct OptBool {
>   char c;
>
>   OptBool() : c(2) { }
>   OptBool(bool b) { new (&c) bool(b); }
>
>   auto has_value() const -> bool {
>     return c != 2;
>   }
>
>   auto operator*() -> bool& {
>     return (bool&)c;
>   }
> };
> ```

However, I am not convinced, and there are issues that raise my eyebrows:

1. There is aliasing between `char` and `bool` here. Is this allowed, even though the `char` is a complete object and does not provide storage for the `bool` inside?
2. Even if strict aliasing isn't violated, does `c` in itself remain valid given that the lifetime of the `char` ended and given that it doesn't provide storage?
3. Does the cast to `bool&` not require `std::launder`, given that the provenance of the obtained reference does not lead back to a `bool` object?

---

*Note: This is a sister question to [Is the author's union-based implementation of an optional<bool> well-defined in P2641?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77162785/is-the-authors-union-based-implementation-of-an-optionalbool-well-defined-in) which discusses the other implementation.*

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `operator*` has a precondition as usual that the `OptBool(bool b)` overload has been used. Using `operator*` when the optional is empty is clearly UB, but also is not intended use.

The first problem is that `new (&c) bool(b);` will end the lifetime of the whole `OptBool` object, although I am not sure that this is currently well-specified when it happens in the constructor. The newly-created `bool` object can't become a member subobject because it doesn't have the same type as `c` and therefore can't be nested within the `OptBool` object. The lifetime of an object ends if its storage is reused by an object not nested within it. This can be fixed by making `c` a `unsigned char[1]` which can provide storage for the `bool` object.

With that change:

If `OptBool(bool b)` was used, then there is a `bool` object at the address of `&c[0]`. However, `std::launder` is required to get a pointer to this `bool` object from the pointer to the `unsigned char` object, because the objects are not pointer-interconvertible, nor transparently-replaceable (as they do not have the same type). So it can be fixed:

```
return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<bool*>(&c[0]));
```

With that fixed, there is however still a problem with `has_value` in that situation. With `new` the lifetime of the `unsigned char` object ended because its storage is reused. Therefore `c[0] != 2` performs a read out-of-lifetime, which is UB.

In order to get a pointer to the `bool` object, but with expression type `unsigned char`, one would have to do this:

```
*reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(std::launder(reinterpret_cast<bool*>(&c[0])))
```

Then this isn't an aliasing violation. However, it is currently not specified what value this access should read. The intention is for it to read the first byte of the object representation of the `bool` object, but that isn't specified to happen at the moment. There is [P1839](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/592) trying to fix that. It is in practice what everyone assumes as the behavior, even if the standard doesn't say that at the moment, which is a defect.

However, if the optional is empty, then `std::launder(reinterpret_cast<bool*>(&c[0]))` has undefined behavior because `std::launder` requires a `bool` object to be alive at the address. I don't think that can be fixed.

Whether or not it was intended that `std::launder` is required in this situation is another question, but that's how it seems to be specified right now.

In any case, the implementation of course assumes a specific implementation of `bool`, specifically its size, alignment and object/value representations.

Comment: Are you sure that `c != 2` is not counted as an aliasing access to the stored `bool` but rather an access past the end of thee lifetime of the `char`? Would the `c` name not refer to the stored `bool` after placement-new? This is really the crux of the issue, and it would be good if the answer contained some standard citation that resolved this question.

Comment: @JanSchultke That's why there is https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#life-8, but it requires the types of the objects to be identical.

Comment: @JanSchultke Leaving this comment here instead of on top level so numeric user can read it too :-). I'll believe this is invalid when either a sanitizer flags it as invalid or somebody demonstrates a compiler optimization that is broken by either implementation. At this point, everyone is [fine with both](https://godbolt.org/z/r1n4sMc9r), and I have very serious doubts that this will ever change.