# Is the author's union-based implementation of an optional<bool> well-defined in P2641?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, unions, type-punning, c++26

In [P2641r4: Checking if a union alternative is active](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2641r4.html), the author provides an implementation of an `optional<bool>` as a motivating example and claims that this is well-formed.

> ```cpp
> struct OptBool {
>   union { bool b; char c; };
>
>   OptBool() : c(2) { }
>   OptBool(bool b) : b(b) { }
>
>   auto has_value() const -> bool {
>     return c != 2;
>   }
>
>   auto operator*() -> bool& {
>     return b;
>   }
> };
> ```

However, I am not convinced. Namely, `has_value()` doens't look to be safe because if a `bool` is the active union member, then `c != 2` accesses an inactive member and performs union type punning. To my knowledge, this is not allowed in C++.

The author explains that it can't be done because an inactive union member is being read, and provides the following implementation:

> ```cpp
>   constexpr auto has_value() const -> bool {
>     if consteval {
>       return std::is_within_lifetime(&b);
>     } else {
>       return c != 2;
>     }
>   }
> ```

What did the author mean by this? Does this mean that you cannot read the inactive union member in a constant expression but it would otherwise be permitted?
Is this code totally well-formed or does it rely on compiler extensions that would permit union type punning at run-time?

---

*Note: This is a sister question to [Is the author's implementation of an optional<bool> well-defined in P2641?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77162697/is-the-authors-implementation-of-an-optionalbool-well-defined-in-p2641) which discusses the other implementation.*

Comment: The union does not seem necessary at all, one can just store the tristate in `bool` alone.

Comment: @Quimby the author's idea is that this is meant to be a specialization of an `optional<T>` for `bool`, so it still needs to have the interface of an optional type.

Comment: IIRC C++ doesn't permit it. But I don't believe that there is a working compiler of C++ that will not accept it or malfunction with it.

Comment: When I mark a question as language lawyer, I hope that Barry (author of that article) shows up. Lawyers use very legit literature to describe things. If you didn't understand the article, it is because of the level of the issue it is addressing. In short, both provided implementations contain some level of UB, or violation of strict aliasing rule. The author is bating that example to start cooking discussion about a consexpr refinement proposal. Otherwise,  `boost::tribool` would be a good candidate for implementing `optional<bool>`: it provides the required functionality, but needs polising.

Comment: It is explained just below: _"Both of these are fine: operator* works because we are returning a reference to a very-much-live bool in both cases, and has_value() works because we are allowed read through a char (explicitly, per [basic.lval]/11.31)."_

Comment: @Quimby You mean `char`, right?

Comment: The code is definitely well-formed. The author additionally claims that it doesn't have undefined behavior. In general the difference is that ill-formed code is incorrect even if it's never evaluated.

Comment: These days, all the platforms I work on have sizeof(char) == sizeof(bool) == 1.  But I have worked on 2 platforms back in the day that had sizeof(bool) == 4.  One platform, with sizeof(bool) == 1, had true represented in memory by *eight ones* (0xFF).  If the code does not need to be portable for these uncommon platforms, and is okay to rely on *implementation defined behavior* allowing type punning via union, it should be okay.

Comment: Type punning using unions is not supported by the language. You can only read from a union member if it was the last one assigned to. A lot of platforms allow it explicitly as an extension.

Comment: @user3840170 Not really, I did mean `bool`, `char` would not allow the wanted `operator*` conversion.

Comment: @Quimby But a `bool` can only hold one of two values.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that `operator*` has a precondition as usual that the `OptBool(bool b)` overload has been used. Using `operator*` when the optional is empty is clearly UB, but also is not intended use.

When `b` is the active member, then accessing the `c` has undefined behavior because it must be out-of-lifetime.

The intent here is to look at the object representation, which can be achieved by adding a seemingly unnecessary cast:

```
return *reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(reinterpret_cast<OptBool*>(&c)) != 2;
```

The inner cast will yield a pointer to the `OptBool` object, because `OptBool` is standard-layout and pointer-interconvertible with the `c` subobject.

The outer cast will then produce a pointer to the `OptBool` object with expression type `unsigned char*`. Accessing through it is not an aliasing violation. However, it is currently not specified what value this access should read. The intention is for it to read the first byte of the object representation of the `OptBool` object (and also the `bool` or `char` object), but that isn't specified to happen at the moment. There is [P1839](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/592) trying to fix that. It is in practice what everyone assumes as the behavior, even if the standard doesn't say that at the moment, which is a defect.

In any case, the implementation of course assumes a specific implementation of `bool`, specifically its size, alignment and object/value representations.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the standard requiring `false` or `true` to not be stored as the value 2.
`int(false)` is required to be 0 and `int(true)` is required to be 1 but those are results of casts, not the value stored in memory.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19351548/362589

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the question. It just means that if the code is well-formed, it still suffers from making assumptions about the platform ABI and the compiler. However, it doesn't answer whether the code is well-formed in the first place.